# How to check a value is UUID in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

Since MariaDB does not have a `UUID` data type, based on search I realized that people usually define a column with `char(36)` as its data type and they can also define a default using `uuid()` function for it.

However, it's still possible for somebody to insert invalid data directly.

I searched for another function like `is_uuid()` to be used a in check constraint.

Is there such a thing in MariaDB? Or should I write my own function for this purpose?

Comment: *Since MariaDB does not have a UUID data type*. in fact it has. The [UUID](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/) data type was added in a MariaDB 10.7.0 preview.

Comment: @ErgestBasha, really? Such good news. At last.

Comment: [uuid blog](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-uuid-data-type/) and [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/).

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?  The latest version(s) have a _datatype_ UUID.

Comment: Pre 10.7 (but at least >= 10.2) you can use a CHECK constraint using REGEPX to check for a valid UUID string

`my_uuid varchar(36) check (msg regexp '^[[:xdigit:]]{8}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{4}-[[:xdigit:]]{12}$')`